# Bash, loop unexpected stop

Tags: bash, loops, curl, scripting

I'm having problems with this last part of my bash script. It receives input from 500 web addresses and is supposed to fetch the server information from each. It works for a bit but then just stops at like the 45 element. Any thoughts with my loop at the end?

```
#initializing variables 
timeout=5
headerFile="lab06.output"
dataFile="fortune500.tsv"
dataURL="http://www.tech.mtu.edu/~toarney/sat3310/lab09/"
dataPath="/home/pjvaglic/Documents/labs/lab06/data/"
curlOptions="--fail --connect-timeout $timeout"

#creating the array
declare -a myWebsitearray

#obtaining the data file
wget $dataURL$dataFile -O $dataPath$dataFile

#getting rid of the crap from dos
sed -n "s/^m//" $dataPath$dataFile

readarray -t myWebsitesarray < <(cut -f3 -d$'\t' $dataPath$dataFile)

myWebsitesarray=("${myWebsitesarray[@]:1}")

websitesCount=${#myWebsitesarray[*]}

echo "There are $websitesCount websites in $dataPath$dataFile"

#echo -e ${myWebsitesarray[200]}

#printing each line in the array
for line in ${myWebsitesarray[*]}
do
echo "$line"
done

#run each website URL and gather header information
for line in "${myWebsitearray[@]}"
    do
        ((count++))
        echo -e "\\rPlease wait... $count of $websitesCount"
        curl --head "$curlOptions" "$line" | awk '/Server: / {print $2 }' >> $dataPath$headerFile       
    done

#display results
echo "Results: "
sort $dataPath$headerFile | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net/ for some important feedback

Comment: also, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I threw it in shellcheck.net and corrected all the smaller errors, but It didn't fix the initial problem.

Comment: Start by removing `--silent` from the options you are passing to `curl`. If one of your `curl` calls fail it could cause an early exit and you would not know.

Comment: Does the "printing each line in the array" loop print all the lines?

Comment: Add `set -x` to your script and see what happens with debug output turned on.

Comment: FYI, the "getting rid of dos crap" sed command doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes, it correctly prints each URL out perfectly fine.

Comment: `printf "%s\n" "${myWebsitesarray[@]}"` would be more succinct and more correct.

Comment: Also I made the corrections. It is strange to me because it is almost like curl isn't doing anything. Or the loop isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly help if you actually passed the --connect-timeout option to curl.  As written, you are currently passing the single argument `--fail --connect-timeout $timeout` rather than 3 distinct arguments `--fail`, `--connect-timeout`, and `$timeout`.  This is one instance where you should not quote the variable.  IOW, use:

```
curl --head $curlOptions "$line"
```

Comment: You do realize this was over a 2 year old post and not am I not in the class anymore but I also already graduated.

Comment: Nope.  Didn't look at the date.  Nor will future readers who may land here looking for a solution.  What you put on the internet stays available forever. :)